# How to find the network id of the ip address

Tags: networking, ip-address

I already have studied about the internet IP and all those stuff, but I'm still confused about how to identify network ID from given IP address, for example, if I have given an IP address: **192.168.45.215/21**, so what will be the network ID?

Comment: this might help you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/subnet-cheat-sheet-24-subnet-mask-30-26-27-29-and-other-ip-address-cidr-network-references/

Answer (score 0):

```
192.168.45.215/21 = 192.168.45.215/255.255.248.0 = 192.168.'b00101101.'b11010111/'b11111111.'b11111111.'b11111000.'b00000000;
```

--so the network id is:

```
'b11000000.'b10101000.'b00101101.'b11010111 &
'b11111111.'b11111111.'b11111000.'b00000000 =
'b11000000.'b10101000.'b00101000.'b00000000 =
192.168.40.0
```

--where '&' is a "bitwise AND":

```
a b  a & b
0 0  0
0 1  0
1 0  0
1 1  1
```